# Upper bound for a subset of $\mathbb{N}^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Question: Consider the set
  $$ A(m) : = \{ (a, b) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : \;  N \leq a \leq 2 N, \;  a^2 - b^2 = m  \}, $$
where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and  $N \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0 \}$.  Then 
$$ \sup_{m \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}} (\sharp A(m)) = O(N^{\epsilon}) \; \mbox{ for all } \epsilon > 0 \; ? $$

Remark: My failed tentative was to use the following result 
related to divisor bounds of a natural number:
$$ \sharp B(\ell) : = \sharp \{ (c, d) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : |c | \leq 2 N, |d| \leq 2 N \mbox{ and }  c \cdot d = \ell \} = O(N^{\epsilon}),$$
but, in the above case we not have information about the localization of $b \in \mathbb N$. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: $m>0$, then $m \leq 4N^2$, so $d(m)=O((4N^2)^{\epsilon})= O(N^\epsilon)$, but then $c=a-b, d=a+b$ are divisors of $m$ so the number of such pairs lies in a $O(N^\epsilon)^2=O(N^\epsilon)$ set, hence $2a=c+d$ is in a $O(N^\epsilon)$ set

Case 2: $m<0, n=-m$ and assume there are at least two distinct solutions $(a,b), (a_1,b_1), N \leq a < a_1 \leq 2N, b^2-a^2=b_1^2-a_1^2=n>0$ as otherwise there is nothing to prove.

Then since $b_1 > b$ it follows that $3N^2 \geq a_1^2-a^2 =b_1^2 - b^2 \geq 2b+1$, so $b=O(N^2), n=|m|=O(N^4), d(m)=O(N^\epsilon)$ and the method from case 1 applies so we are done

Comment: Dear @Conrad, Case 1 was clear to understand, because $m > 0$ implies $b \in [0, 2N]$ say. But Case 2 remains unclear.

Comment: Why? I showed that if there are at least two solutions $|m| = O(N^4)$, so the same reasoning applies, number of divisors of $m$ is $O(N^{\epsilon})$, pairs of such same, $a$ is the semisum of such, so same bound applies

Comment: I realize that $b_1 > b$ implies $b_1 \geq b + 1$ . Therefore,$b_1^2 \geq (b + 1)^2$ and $b_1^2 - b^2 \geq 2 b + 1$.  But,  the existence of two solutions no implies necessarily a global  bound for the value of $b$ ?

Comment: $2b+1 \leq b_1^2-b^2=a_1^2-a^2 \leq 3N^2$, so $b$ is bounded by ~$N^2$, hence $m$ is bounded by ~$N^4$

Comment: Yes, but the same is not valid for $b_1$, so there exists a problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter since the bound for $|m|$ matters - note that actually it implies bound for $b_1$ too since $b_1^2 \leq |m|+ 4N^2$, so $b_1$ is bounded by ~$N^2$

Comment: So, the set $A(m)$ above having at least two elements imposes a fairly strong constraint on the size of $|m|$, namely being bounded by ~$N^4$; intuitively this is actually clear (not the precise bound, but that a power bound must exist) since if $|m|$ is much bigger than $a$ it follows that $b$ is about $\sqrt{|m|}$ and $b-a, b+a$ are both about $b$ as $a$ is negligible, but there is no way a number has two distinct pairs of complementary divisors ($d, \frac{|m|}{d}$) this close to its square root for a sufficiently small "this close" and the computations above put a numeric value on that